# Using Delimiter when reading lines from a textfile in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve really. Currently I'm reading a couple of lines from a textfile but there's some values in the lines that I don't want to keep. The lines are like

int String Float float float

I only want to have the string part and assign that name to a listbox. I tried using a delimiter just for a space but I realized that it's not reseting to the start of the next line but keeps going on from the last place.

The first lines of the textfile is

> 1 Betong  1.7 .24 2300
>
> 2   Armerad Betong   1.28   .26 2100
>
> 3   Cementbruk  .93 .29 1800

Using a delimiter with a space gives me

> 1
>
> Armerad
>
> .93

While I would like it to at least be

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

The code I have right now is that is a procedure for a onClickEvent for a button

```
  var
   SomeTxtFile : TextFile;
   buffer : string;
   holder : TStringList;
   idx:integer;
 begin
 idx:=-1;
  holder:=TStringList.Create;
   AssignFile(SomeTxtFile, 'Opaque.lib') ;
   Reset(SomeTxtFile) ;
   while not EOF(SomeTxtFile) do
   begin
   idx:=idx+1;
    ReadLn(SomeTxtFile, buffer) ;
    holder.Delimiter:=' ';
    holder.DelimitedText:=buffer;
    ShowMessage(buffer) ;
    WallsListBox.Items.Add(holder[idx]);
   end;
   CloseFile(SomeTxtFile) ;
```

I'm thinking that maybe I could do what I want with a lot of flags that tries to convert parts of the string to float/integer but this seems very stupid. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: You add to the listbox holder[idx]. And idx gets incremented at every line you read. You should add holder[0] to the listbox.

Comment: If you want to do yourself a favour, throw out all those TextFile routines and use streams instead. Every times someone uses AssignFile() a kitten dies.

Comment: @JensG I have no knowledge of how to use streams, so I'm sorry but I'll guess I'll have to be a kitten murderer :/

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing idx'th element of list. To print first elements, use

```
WallsListBox.Items.Add(holder[0]);
```

to print second (string) part - use

```
WallsListBox.Items.Add(holder[1]);
```

and so on. Note that string parts may contain some words (Armerad Betong), so you'll need analyze `holder` contents. Example:

```
var
  TextList, Holder: TStringList;
  s: string;
  i, j: integer;
  dummy: Double;
begin
  TextList := TStringList.Create;
  Holder := TStringList.Create;
  TextList.LoadFromFile('Opaque.lib');
  for i := 0 to TextList.Count - 1 do begin
    Holder.CommaText := TextList[i];
    if Holder.Count >= 2 then begin
      s := Holder[1];
      j := 2;
      while (j < Holder.Count) and
        (not TryStrToFloat(Holder[j], dummy)) do begin
        s := s + ' ' + Holder[j];
        Inc(j);
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
    end;
  end;
  Holder.Free;
  TextList.Free;
```

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thanks! By analyze the holder contents I need to do some kind of flags probably right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a TStringList to "delimit" the text (it won't work when there are spaces in the string you want to extract), I'd use an alternate approach: Remove the last three words and the first word (space-delimited) from the string. What remains must be the text you are after (assuming that all lines contains exactly the format int String Float float float):

```
var
   SomeTxtFile : TextFile;
   buffer : string;
   idx:integer;

begin
  AssignFile(SomeTxtFile, 'Opaque.lib') ;
  Reset(SomeTxtFile) ;
  while not EOF(SomeTxtFile) do begin
    ReadLn(SomeTxtFile, buffer);
    ShowMessage(buffer);
    idx:=length(buffer);
    // First eliminitate all trailing spaces
    while buffer[idx]=' ' do dec(idx);
    // Then eliminate the third float value (search backwards for the space seperator)
    while buffer[idx]<>' ' do dec(idx);
    // Then eliminitate all spaces before the third float value
    while buffer[idx]=' ' do dec(idx);
    // Then eliminate the second float value (search backwards for the space seperator)
    while buffer[idx]<>' ' do dec(idx);
    // Then eliminitate all spaces before the second float value
    while buffer[idx]=' ' do dec(idx);
    // Then eliminate the first float value (search backwards for the space seperator)
    while buffer[idx]<>' ' do dec(idx);
    // Then eliminitate all spaces before the first float value
    while buffer[idx]=' ' do dec(idx);
    // Truncate the string to elimate all the characters we have determined to be the float values and their seperating spaces
    setlength(buffer,idx);
    // Now search from the beginning of the string
    idx:=1;
    // First eliminate all leading spaces
    while buffer[idx]=' ' do inc(idx);
    // Then eliminate the integer value
    while buffer[idx]<>' ' do inc(idx);
    // Then eliminate the spaces following the integer value
    while buffer[idx]=' ' do inc(idx);
    // We are now at the first character of the string we want, so step back one character
    dec(idx);
    // Delete the characters from the string that we have determined to be the integer value and the spaces surrounding it
    delete(buffer,1,idx);
    WallsListBox.Items.Add(buffer);
  end;
  CloseFile(SomeTxtFile);
end.
```

You could also use the built-in POS functions, but I believe the above code will be easier understood for one that (as it seems - no offense) only has a rudimentary knowledge of the Delphi/PASCAL language.